# MonoTouch DateElement - Get the value

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How to get the value of DateElement after I changed the day/month/year for example. Everytime I changed one of them, the DateValue property is still the old value, but the Value property is changed.

Comment: You will get more help if you provide examples of your code so we can better understand your request, and demonstrate you have tried to resolve it on your own first.

Comment: If you don't show us what you are doing, we can't tell you what you might be doing wrong

Comment: Hi all, 

This what I did in the code

//in the constructor
DateElement deDOB = new DateElement("DOB", DateTime.Today);

Then, when I ran into simulator, It shows current date in the both the form and the picker (Sept 3, 2013). I changed the value in the picker, let's say to last year (Sept 3, 2012).

Then, OnTouchUpInside event of a button, I call

Console.Out.WriteLine(deDOB.DateValue);

It printed in the console 9/3/2013 5:00:00 PM

What I expected is 9/3/2012.